# Can I limit the number of emails the AOL sends to iPhone?

Tags: email, iphone

I only want to have a limited number of emails be sent to my iPhone, the most curretn 20 to 40, how can I do this?

Comment: per hour, per day, forever ?

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the amount fetched from all of your mail accounts, but it cannot be set independently for just the AOL account.  In the settings menu, go to "Mail, Contacts, Calendars" and below where the accounts are listed, there is a section called "Mail".  The first option there "Show", which limits the mails which are fetched.  It can't be set below 50, though.